# SIGABRT with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I thought I had set everything up right in my code (after 2 million stupid questions here on stack ... thanks for patience :) )

BUT, of course, it crashes when running on device. I have a soundboard, and on one specific button, it crashes and gives a SIGABRT signal recived and highlights this in thread:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"mp3"];
**AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];**
[theAudio setDelegate: self];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
[theAudio setVolume:1.0];
[theAudio play];
```

I have released it this way:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [player release];
}
```

Any help?

Comment: you profile says you have asked 2 questions on SO. Where are all these other previously asked questions you refer to?

Comment: @Mitch - Comments, probably. But definitely not that many.

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake. Just a good old typo... :)

Comment: haha, sorry guys, I´ve used my other e-mail on that ones. And ok, I admit, I havent asked 2 million questions. But at least 10 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's wise to release the `player` passed in to you, because you didn't explicitly allocate, retain, or copy it.

It's possible that the player passed in to you is a different object than the one you originally allocated.

I would suggest when you allocate the player originally, keep a reference to it. When the ending callback is called, check to see if the pointers match, and if so release your pointer (and nil it out).

But my best guess is when you allocate the player on your highlighted line, that it's been passed a nil path string. You should check to see if that's the error. Otherwise it sounds like a memory problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. What happend in the above code was that I had named the audiofile the wrong way ("Sound" instead of "sound") so when I found the problem and renamed it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, i hit the enterbutton to fast. Did not mean to answer rude. Do you have a sample code or way to release the way you are talking about? I am new to obj-c, Only been coding for some 2-3 months. All help is highly appriciated. Thank you!